# Matplotlib cycler doesn't work with hatches

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, visualization

Given the following example

```
%matplotlib notebook

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cycler import cycler

bar_cycler = (cycler(color=["#E69F00", "#56B4E9"]) +
             cycler(hatch=["/" , "o"]))

plt.rc("axes", prop_cycle=bar_cycler)


data = {
  "calories": [420, 380, 390],
  "duration": [50, 40, 45]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.plot(stacked=True, kind='bar')
```

This produces the following image, i.e., it works for the color but doesn't take the hatching into account.

[image]

How do I make cyclers and hatching work?

Answer (score 0):

Not all kind of plot can use `hatch` and maybe this is problem.

But you can plot it using two `bar()`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = {
  "calories": [420, 380, 390],
  "duration": [50, 40, 45]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(["1","2","3"], df['calories'], hatch='/', color="#E69F00")
ax.bar(["1","2","3"], df['duration'], hatch='*', color="#56B4E9", bottom=df['calories'])

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

Matplotlib documentation: [Stacked bar chart](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_stacked.html), [Hatch demo](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/shapes_and_collections/hatch_demo.html), [Hatch style reference](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/shapes_and_collections/hatch_style_reference.html)

---

**EDIT:**

I found similar question and one answer uses the same method with two `bar()` but other answer sets `hatch` after drawing bars.

[python - matplotlib: assigning different hatch to bars - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55826167/matplotlib-assigning-different-hatch-to-bars)

And I made version which set hatch after drawing but I used `itertool.cycle` because it was more useful in this situation.

Every `bar()` creates many `Rectangles` which are in `BarContainer` and this need nested `for`-loops.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cycler import cycler

bar_cycler = cycler(color=["#E69F00", "#56B4E9"])
             
plt.rc("axes", prop_cycle=bar_cycler)

data = {
  "calories": [420, 380, 390],
  "duration": [50, 40, 45]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

ax = df.plot(stacked=True, kind='bar')

# ---

import itertools

cycle_hatch = itertools.cycle(["/" , "o"])

for container, hatch in zip(ax.containers, cycle_hatch):
    for item in container.patches:
        item.set_hatch(hatch)
    
# ---     

plt.show()
```

---

**EDIT:**

Other similar question - but it set different hatch for every Rectangle in BarContainer.

[python - How to to add stacked bar plot hatching in pandas? (...or how to get BarContainer vs AxisSubplot in pandas plot vs. matplotlib?) - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59585813/how-to-to-add-stacked-bar-plot-hatching-in-pandas-or-how-to-get-barcontaine)